# Help with assembler code

Tags: assembly, x86

```
push eax 
push ecx 
and eax,0x3C 
ror eax,1 
ror eax,1 
inc eax 
mov edx,eax 
pop eax 
xor eax,edx 
pop ecx 
xor eax,ecx 
rol al,1 
ret
```

can anybody help me understand what this code is doing by commenting it and why we do such routines like and and ror? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
push eax - saves eax to stack
push ecx - saves ecx to stack
and eax,0x3C - logical AND register eax with 0x3c ( 111100 in binary) - this means that only 4 bits starting from bit 2 are interesting - in C : a = a & 

0x3C;
ror eax,1 - rotate one bit right - in C : a = a >> 1;
ror eax,1 - rotate one bit right - in C : a = a >> 1; so after this command these 4 interesting bits starting in position 0;
inc eax - increse these 4 bits value by one - in C : a++;
mov edx,eax - copy value from register eax to register edx
pop eax - load value from stack (value that was previously in ecx) and copy it to eax registry
xor eax,edx - xor value from stack(previously ecx) with incremented 4bits value - in C : b = b ^ a;
pop ecx - load value from stack (value that was previously in eax) and copy it to ecx registry
xor eax,ecx - xor value from stack(previously eax) once again - in C : c = c ^ b;
rol al,1 - rotate left by one bit the last byte (al) of registry eax - in C : c = (unsigned char)c << 1;
ret - return from function - probably this what is in EAX is a return value
```

So more or less this is how this function could looks like in C

```
unsigned char func1(unsigned int parm1, insigned int parm2)
{
  unsigned int a = par1 & 0x3C;
  a = a >> 1;
  a = a >> 1;
  a++;
  a = parm2 ^ a;
  a = parm1 ^ a;
  return (unsigned char)a << 1;
}
```

Comment: The `return (unsigned char)...` bit is incorrect, because the use of `AL` doesn't modify the higher bits of `EAX`, which are not zero, at least in the case of the arguments having non-zero upper bits. The function therefore _either_ returns a full 32bit value, _or_ expects the two arguments to be actual 8bit (all upper bits clear).

Answer (score 3):

This code does the same as:

```
unsigned int func(arg0, arg1)
{
    unsigned int tmp = (arg1 ^ (((arg0 & 0x3C) >> 2) + 1)) ^ arg0;
    unsigned char c = (unsigned char)(tmp & 0xff);
    return (tmp & ~0xff) | (unsigned int)((c << 7) | (c >> 1));
}
```

If I read it all right, that is. Quite convoluted - where's it from ?

In any case, for the details:

Start with: From the use of `EAX` / `ECX` as arguments, it can be seen that this uses Microsoft's `__fastcall` calling convention (`arg0` of a function in `EAX`, `arg1` in `ECX`).

Then just follow the arithmetic through. Apart from the *last* use of rotation on `AL` only, it's actually simple then:

```
push eax         ; saves arg0 to stack
push ecx         ; saves arg1 to stack
and eax,0x3C     ; tmp = arg0 & 0x3C (this isolates bits 3-6, makes all else zero)
ror eax,1        ;
ror eax,1        ; twice rot right. Since upper bits are zero: tmp >>= 2;
inc eax          ; tmp++
mov edx,eax      ; EDX = tmp
pop eax          ; retrieve last item on stack, tmp2 = arg1
xor eax,edx      ; tmp2 ^= tmp;
pop ecx          ; retrieve prev item on stack, tmp3 = arg0
xor eax,ecx      ; tmp2 ^= tmp3
                 ;     full line: (arg1 ^ (((arg0 & 0x3C) >> 2) + 1)) ^ arg0
rol al,1         ; complex ... rotate lowest byte right by one
                 ;            al = (al >> 1) | (al << 7)
                 ; 
ret
```

Edit: Zuljin gave me an idea here ... if the function actually operates on *bytes* explicitly, then it can be stated in a simpler way:

```
char transmogrify(char arg0, char arg1)
{
    char tmp = (arg1 ^ (((arg0 << 2) >> 4) + 1))) ^ arg0;
    return ((tmp << 7) | (tmp >> 1));
}
```

This sort of `rotate(a ^ X ^ b, 1)` operation is used as part of some ciphers like DES, but what exactly you have depends on the `X` (which is just a bit shuffle here). I'm not a cryptography expert, and don't recognize the specific case. It'd be interesting if someone can fill the gap in ...

Comment: Its from Uni, for a decryption program but i ended up missing a load of lectures so i dont have a clue about it, i have to comment it for an excersize

Answer (score 1):

```
push eax            ; pushing eax into stack
push ecx            ; pushing ecx into stack
and eax,0x3C        ; performs logical and operation on eax and 0x3C
ror eax,1           ; one bit right shift value from eax with carrying shifted bit to most significant bit (cyclic right shift)
ror eax,1           ; one bit right shift value from eax with carrying shifted bit to most significant bit (cyclic right shift)
inc eax         ; increment eax value
mov edx,eax         ; copy value from eax to edx
pop eax         ; restore eax value from stack, which was pushed by this command "push ecx"
xor eax,edx         ; exclusive or operation on eax and edx values
pop ecx         ; restore ecx value from stack, which was pushed by this command "push eax"
xor eax,ecx         ; exclusive or operation on eax and ecx values
rol al,1            ; one bit left shift value from al (least significant byte from eax) with carrying shifted bit to least significant bit (cyclic left shift)
ret             ; return from function
```

and I suggest you to read some articles from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199679/good-beginners-books-for-assembly-languages

Comment: Thanks mate, do you no why we and it together and what the point in doing it is. Same for rotateing left and right?

Comment: This looks like some strange sort of checksum; where's the code from ?